# Missing [assembly:RuntimePlugin] attribute in SpecFlowPlugin

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, specflow

I've created a SpecFlow Plugin following their page below. And have created a Generator Plugin as I needed to modify the auto generated code behind my features.

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Plugins.

SpecFlowPlugin Code

```
[assembly: GeneratorPlugin(typeof(SpecFlowSpiraAdapterPlugin))]
namespace SpiraTest.SpecFlowPlugin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A adapterpPlugin is needed to use a custom MSTest generator with SpecFlow.
    /// </summary>
    public class SpecFlowSpiraAdapterPlugin : IGeneratorPlugin
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// By implementing the Initialize- Method on the IGeneratorPlugin interface, you get access to the GeneratorPluginEvents and GeneratorPluginParameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="generatorPluginEvents"></param>
        /// <param name="generatorPluginParameters"></param>
        public void Initialize(GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, GeneratorPluginParameters generatorPluginParameters)
        {
            generatorPluginEvents.CustomizeDependencies += GeneratorPluginEvents_CustomizeDependencies;
        }       

        private void GeneratorPluginEvents_CustomizeDependencies(object sender, CustomizeDependenciesEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs<MSTestCustomGenerator, IUnitTestGeneratorProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

I'm getting an error message when trying to run my tests indicating that i don't have the below attribute.

> [assembly:RuntimePlugin] attribute

However I don't need that attribute as I have the [assembly: GeneratorPlugin] attribute instead.

No idea why it's saying that. Any ideas?

---

> Message: Class Initialization method
>   MiJobsAdminPortal.UITests.Login.LoginFeature.FeatureSetup threw
>   exception. TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException:
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException: Missing [assembly:RuntimePlugin]
>   attribute in SpiraTest.SpecFlowPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Please check
>   http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SpecFlow every plugin is a Generator and a Runtime plugin, except you configure it otherwise. This is the code for that: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/Infrastructure/ContainerBuilder.cs#L127

As an example for configuration, have a look at the configuration of the SpecFlow+Excel plugin, which is also only a generator plugin.

```
<specFlow>
    <plugins>
      <add name="SpecFlow.Plus.Excel" type="Generator" />
    </plugins>
</specFlow>
```

You have to specify the type as `Generator`. If not SpecFlow is always searching for both plugin types.

This behaviour is not documented, but is there since years. I will update the documentation in the next days.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of SpecFlow & SpecFlow+

Comment: Yep that was it. Yea I agree you should probably add that in to the documentation as I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: First thing tomorrow. No idea how that could have slipped through.

Comment: Where can I find the example configuration for the Excel plugin?